# RegEx for processing WordPress shortcode

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I am trying to find a suitable regex for processing WordPress shortcodes. Created an expression but it doesn't process all conditions.

**Expression**

`\[feature([^\]]*)\]([^\]]*)\[\/feature\]`

**Example text**

```
[feature title="Call us at" width="4" icon="fa-thumbs-up"]my phone is[/feature]

// shortcodes without linebrakes between
[feature title="Call us at" width="4" icon="fa-thumbs-up"]my phone is[/feature][feature title="Call us at" width="4" icon="fa-thumbs-up"]my phone is[/feature]


// with nested shortcode inside attributes


[feature title="Call us at [phone]" width="4" icon="fa-thumbs-up"]my phone is [other][/feature]


[feature title="Call us at [phone] sfdfasd" width="4" icon="fa-thumbs-up"]my phone is [other] dssafsd[/feature]
```

First two example works but for the nested shortcodes regex fails.

Here is the link for you to play with https://regex101.com/r/zA4iH4/7

Comment: In WordPress you don't parse the shortcodes yourself use the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and understand that there are [limitations with nested shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Limitations)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention. I am using JS not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically if you check the [documentation for shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes) you will find **Attribute values** **must never contain** the following characters:

- Square braces: `[` `]`
- Quotes: `"` `'`

So your sample text above is **not strictly valid for WordPress** and you will likely have other issues.

---

As long as you don't have nested `[feature...]` tags (where a `[feature]` is inside a `[feature]`) and no square braces in attributes:

### Regular Expression

```
\[feature([^\]]*)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/feature\]
```

### Human Readable

```
// \[feature([^\]]*)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/feature\]
// 
// Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks
// 
// Match the character “[” literally «\[»
// Match the character string “feature” literally (case insensitive) «feature»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\]]*)»
//    Match any character that is NOT a “]” «[^\]]*»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
// Match the character “]” literally «\]»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\s\S]*?)»
//    Match a single character present in the list below «[\s\S]*?»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
//       A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
//       Any character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\S»
// Match the character “[” literally «\[»
// Match the character “/” literally «\/»
// Match the character string “feature” literally (case insensitive) «feature»
// Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```

Comment: It is not working when there is any [nested shortcode inside attributes](https://regex101.com/r/zA4iH4/8).

Comment: Added support matched pair double quotes used for parameters, although it should be noted that WordPress explicitly doesn't support use of shortcodes in parameter / attribute values.

Comment: Specifically if you check the [documentation for shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes) you will find Attribute values must never contain the following characters:

Square braces: `[ ]` and Quotes: `" '`

Comment: Updated answer to remove updated regular expression as it would not be strictly valid for WordPress.

Comment: yes, you are correct. Putting shortcodes inside attribute values is bad practice until WP core supports it! Thanks!

Comment: Be aware I don't believe that WordPress will support it for backwards compatibility reasons - it would require changes to a great number of plugins - you might be waiting years for that to happen.